# How should I vote to close this question

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I'm a bit confused since the change of close vote reasons. How should I vote to close the following question, now that *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate some minimum knowledge and an attempt"* has been removed from the close votes?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109231/javascript-to-dynamically-choose-a-link-from-a-given-set-and-display

> only client side code to dynamically choose a value from a static
>   array and displayed. This link must be linked dynamically to it's
>   corresponding page. And each time the element chosen is different on
>   running code.Any ideas?

I noticed that since the question has -6 votes, I'm not alone in this confusion. Do we just downvote these kind of questions now?

Comment: Nope, we also close them as "unclear what you're asking". I read that question four times and still cannot make any sense of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the obvious correct answer is 'Unclear what you're asking':

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

It is entirely possible that the people who downvoted all do not have the reputation required to close questions (3000), so they simply downvoted instead (although, they really should use the flag dialog for that).

Comment: Tooltip on downvote button contains "unclear" as downvote reason too, so why should they flag *instead*? They are free to both flag and downvote or use only one of these mechanisms as they see fit, both apply to unclear questions.

Comment: @Mołot you should always flag with a close reason instead of downvote in my opinion, as it places it in both the moderator queue and the close votes queue, making it more likely to actually be closed, as opposed to just downvoting, which tends to bury the question altogether.

Comment: But why **instead**?

Comment: @Mołot like I said - so that the question actually gets closed instead of buried.

Comment: So why don't you post a feature request to remove "unclear" from downvote button description? And what if I don't think it's unclear enough to be closed?

Comment: @Mołot because I've never noticed the tooltip before, and frankly I have better things to do with my time.

Comment: I really don't see a down-side to burying these, @Richard - it may actually be preferable to closing them in many instances.